# Spark CSV Handle Corrupt GZip Files

Tags: csv, apache-spark, gzip, spark-csv

I have a spark 2.0 java application that is using sparks csv reading utilities to read a CSV file into a dataframe.  The problem is that sometimes 1 out of 100 input files may be invalid ( corrupt gzip ) which causes the job to fail with:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Error reading from input
```

When I used to read the files as text files and manually parse the CSV I was able to write a custom TextInputFormat to handle exceptions.  I can't figure out how to specify a customer TextInputFormat when using spark's CSV reader. Any help would be appreciated.

Current code for reading CSV:

```
        Dataset<Row> csv = sparkSession.read()
            .option("delimiter", parseSettings.getDelimiter().toString())
            .option("quote", parseSettings.getQuote())
            .option("parserLib", "UNIVOCITY")
            .csv(paths);
```

Thanks,
Nathan